# How to properly install csdtoolbox-remote?

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I am having trouble installing the [cdstoolbox-remote](https://pypi.org/project/cdstoolbox-remote/) on my Linux machine (tried both Ubuntu and Debian). I installed it using pip:

```
pip install cdstoolbox-remote
```

Which successfully installs the module, but I can't import the module in Python. Importing the module causes the following error:

```
>>> import cdstoolbox
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
File "/home/an/miniconda2/envs/tools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cdstoolbox/__init__.py",  
line 8, in <module>  
with open(__main__.__file__) as f:  
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'
```

What can be done to get it working?

Comment: Version 0.0.1, development status 3 - Alpha. Homepage link points to a login page. Doesn't seem to be useable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need cdstoolbox-remote? The standard API for downloading data from CDS would be cdsapi, which can be installed using

```
pip install cdsapi
```

or using conda (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cdsapi)

I also just tried installing cdstoolbox-remote and got the same problem. But as it is flagged as experimental I even consider it to be possible that the current version is not a stable version.
And cdsapi seems to work.

Comment: cdsapi does work, very good. The problem with it, not actually a problem but a limitation with the CDS store is that it doesn't have daily means of the data. So you'll have to use the cdstoolbox to process the data and then download it. To do that, you have to use the cdstoolbox in the browser, which is a bit inefficient when downloading several TBs of data, spanning several years and variables. It would be better if there's a module which let's you place the cdstoolbox requests from a terminal rather than from a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the CDSAPI can also be used to execute workflows as follows:

```py
import cdsapi
 
c = cdsapi.Client()
 
with open("workflow.py") as f:
    code = f.read()
 
r = c.workflow(code)
print(c.download(r))
```

For more, read [this thread](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/COPSRV/Call+a+service+with+the+CDS+API) on the Copernicus services documentation.